# java.lang.ClassCastException: ca.scooter.talkufy.activities.Updates cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android

When trying to cast to android.app.activity I get thrown this error. I am trying to implement an in-app updater for my app.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ca.scooter.talkufy/ca.scooter.talkufy.activities.Updates}: java.lang.ClassCastException: ca.scooter.talkufy.activities.Updates cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: ca.scooter.talkufy.activities.Updates cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Here is my code of were I am trying to cast from;

```
package ca.scooter.talkufy.activities;

import android.app.Application;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.lzy.okgo.OkGo;
import com.zhy.http.okhttp.OkHttpUtils;


public class Updates extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        getApplicationContext();


        OkHttpUtils.getInstance()
                .init(this)
                .debug(false, "okHttp")
                .timeout(20 * 1000);

        OkGo.getInstance().init(this);
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me that would be great! Thanks.

Comment: ```Updates``` class is extending ```Application``` and as per the exception it is expecting a type of ``Activity``` class.

Comment: I looked at the git repo for OkHttpUtils but do not see an init method, however I suspect your issue is in that call.